# How to specify bean`s "id" property in Spring?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a class MyBean with some fields including String "id".
I have a lot of xml-defined beans with IDs. 
I want to fill "id" fields of MyBean java objects to xml-specified bean IDs. How to implement this without code duplicaton?

```
package just.artmmslv.example.MyBean
public class MyBean {
    private String id;
    private String foo;
//getters, setters, other fields
}

<beans xmlns="foobar+util">
    <util:list value-type="just.artmmslv.example.MyBean">
       <bean id="exampleBean01" class="just.artmmslv.example.MyBean">
           <property name="foo" value="bar"/>
       </bean>
       <!--Other beans-->
    </util:list>
</beans>
```

So, how to make exampleBean01`s field id to be equal to "exampleBean01" in convenient way?

Comment: I think I remember, back in the old (pre-Annotation-Spring)-days, we had to define the ID for every bean, but I am not sure, if there's another way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make id in MyBean of type String, not int (I see int in your code)

Make MyBean implements BeanNameAware

Implement method setBeanName in MyBean:

```
@Override
public void setBeanName(String s) {
    this.id = s;
}
```

That's all you need

Answer (score 0):

I think Spring provides a way to do this via `BeanNameAware`. 
Read through: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-aware-beannameaware

Interface to be implemented by beans that want to be aware of their bean name in a bean factory. Note that it is not usually recommended that an object depend on its bean name, as this represents a potentially brittle dependence on external 
configuration, as well as a possibly unnecessary dependence on a Spring API.